# How to close a View Controller after Performing segue in Xcode?

Tags: ios, swift

My storyboard looks something like this:-

```
Main View Controller -> Game View Controller -> Game Result View Controller
```

I have performed a modal segue from Main V.C to the Game V.C. Now when I perform a modal segue from Game V.C. to Game Result V.C., the Game V.C. is not closing and since the Game V.C. detects if touches began, it crashes when it detects touch outside the  Game V.C. after performing a modal segue to the Game Result V.C. I am not using a navigation View Controller. Could anyone please help me on how shall I close the Game V.C after performing a modal segue to the Game Result V.C.? Would appreciate your help! Thanks:)

```
**Game V.C.** 

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
  // First touch to start the game
  if gameState == .ready {
    startGame()
  }
  
  if let touchLocation = event?.allTouches?.first?.location(in: self.view) {
    // Move the player to the new position
    movePlayer(to: touchLocation)
    
    // Move all enemies to the new position to trace the player
    moveEnemies(to: touchLocation)
  }

}

func gameOver() {
    stopGame()
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "2to3segue", sender: self)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Some tips:

#### Method 1

You can use Tap controller, let storyboard works as following

```
      Main View Controller -> (tab-1) Game View Controller 
                            \ 
                             -> (tab-2) Game Result View Controller
```

[Hide tab bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28777943/hide-tab-bar-in-ios-swift-app/28778105), and change tab by program.

I suggest to use `method 1`.

#### Method 2

Dismiss `Game View Controller`, **WITHOUT** animation. And then present `Game Result View Controller` **WITH** animation.

But, I remember `method 2` has some problems. I used it before, and finally I use `method 1` now.

```
 // Example:
 // Two or more animations will produce problem.
 v2.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil);
 v.present(v3, animated: true, completion: nil);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Could you provide any other solution instead of using a tab bar controller? Thanks:)

Comment: Hmm, you can try `Method 2`, if you don't want to use tab bar controller. But I remember `Method 2` has some UI issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
First dismiss the "v2" view controller and in completion block present "v3" view controller

v2.dismiss(animated: false, completion: {
  v.present(v3, animated: true, completion: nil)
})

or

if v2 is your presented view controller then :

self.presentedViewController.dismiss(animated: false, completion: {
     v.present(v3, animated: true, completion: nil)
 })
```